# Axioms for the real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a field with a total order  which verifies

If $x,y\geq 0$, then $x+y\geq 0$      (here we relax the compatibility property for the addition).

If $x,y\geq 0$, then $xy\geq 0$.

Suppose also that every upper bounded  nonempty set has a supremum.

We don't assume that  $x\leq 0, -x\leq 0$ implies $x=0$.

Is this field the ordered field  of real numbers?

Comment: How can you expect such a thing with absolutely no axiom on the negative numbers except the sup one (which does not relate to the addition/multiplication)? Concatenating the standard order on non-negatives and any total order on the negatives (for which bounded above subsets have a supremum) gives plenty of examples.

Comment: @YCor, worse than this, there can be any total order on strictly positive reals and any total order on strictly negative reals, and then let $\ 0\ $ be inbetween the positive and negative reals.

Comment: For another quick counterexample, choose any lub ordering on $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$, and concatenate $0$ on either side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. E.g., let $R$ be the field of all real numbers with the strict total order $\prec$ defined as follows: for any $x$ and $y$ in $R$ such that $x<y$ (where $<$ is the usual order on $R$), let $x\prec y$ if $y\ge0$, and $y\prec x$ if $y<0$. Then all your conditions on the total order will hold, but $(R,\prec)$ will not be an ordered field.

**Details:**
We see that the order $\prec$ preserves the usual order among the nonnegative real numbers, but reverses the usual order among the negative real numbers, also keeping the negative numbers less than the nonnegative ones.

Since the $\prec$-nonnegative numbers are the same as the $<$-nonnegative ones, your first two conditions, concerning the addition and multiplication operations, hold.

Now take any nonempty $\prec$-upper-bounded subset $A$ of $R$. If there is a nonnegative number in $A$, then $A$ is $<$-upper-bounded, and $\sup_{\prec} A=\sup_{<} A\in R$; the subscripts $_\prec$ and $_<$ indicate here the order with respect to which the supremum or infimum is taken.

Otherwise, that is, if there is no nonnegative number in $A$, then $A$ is always $\prec$-upper-bounded by $0$. If now $c:=\inf_< A\ne-\infty$, then $c=\sup_\prec A\in R$. Finally, if $c=-\infty$, then $\sup_\prec A=0\in R$.

So, any nonempty $\prec$-upper-bounded subset $A$ of $R$ has $\sup_\prec A\in R$. Thus, your third, and final, condition on the total order holds as well.

However, $(R,\prec)$ is not an ordered field, because $-1\prec-2$ but $-1+1\not\prec-2+1$.